# Interpolated coordinates for scaled/zoomed containers

Tags: javascript, css

Working with CSS zoom/scale, I found out that some of my mouse handlers were not working as expected anymore. I have created the following JSFiddle to play around with this problem: https://jsfiddle.net/2wb82x93/1/ . A box will follow your mouse. When you scale the wrapper (using the buttons), the box still follows your mouse, but with an offset and different speed. This makes sense: we translate the box according to non-scaled coordinates.

The code is roughly the following:

**HTML**

```
<div class="sub">
    <div class="container"></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var offset = $('div.sub').offset();
  $('div.sub').mousemove(function(e){
      var x = e.pageX;
      var y = e.pageY;
      $('div.container').css({
        'left': x - offset.left,
        'top':  y - offset.top
      }); 
  });
});
```

And then we scale/zoom the sub div.

Is there a possibility to get retrieve/calculate interpolated coordinates? Or another way to fix this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this problem by calculating the amount of zoom on the element manually, and then divide my coordinate offsets by this zoom factor.

First I have created the following recursive function that takes an element and computes the applied zoom on that element.

```js
function calculateZoom(element) {
  var ownZoom = parseFloat(element.style.zoom || 1);
  if(element !== document.body) {
    ownZoom *= calculateZoom(element.parentElement);
  }
  return ownZoom;
}
```

Then in my mouse event handlers I divide the offsets with the calculated value:

```js
function mousehandler(element) {
  var relxpos = Math.round(event.pageX / this.zoomFactor) - this.center.left,
      relypos = Math.round(event.pageY / this.zoomFactor) - this.center.top;
  // Do computation with relxpos and relypos
}
```

When dragging against these values, the element stays on the cursor in zoomed elements as well!